# focus specific part of page after redirect in php

Tags: php, html, redirect, fat-free-framework

On button click event, I want to redirect to a specific section of page (a form in my case) and also put a `focus` on that section.

How do I achieve that focus?

```
<button class="btn btn-primary" id="addNewRequest" onclick="window.location='<?php echo Utility::getBaseUrl();?>leave/request/#addEmergencyLeave'">Add New Request</button>
```

Here's a form I want to point to and focus

```
<div>
<form id="addEmergencyLeave" method="POST" action="<?php echo Utility::getBaseUrl();?>addEmergencyLeave">
    <select name="user_id" class="select2-container form-control" id="employee_list">
        <option></option>
        <option></option>

    </select>
    <select id="EmergencyLeaveType" class="select2-container form-control" name="EmergencyLeaveType">
        <option></option>
        <option value="2">Personal Leave</option>
        <option value="1">Sick Leave</option>
        <option value="6">Substitute/Others Leave</option>
        <option value="7">Special Leave</option>
    </select>

    <select name="emergency_leave_length" class="select2-container form-control" id="emergency_leave_length">
        <option></option>
        <option value="0">Full Day</option>
        <option value="1">First Half</option>
        <option value="2">Second Half</option>   
    </select>

    <div class="form-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit" value="" name="EmergencyLeaveSubmit">Submit and Approve Leave</button>
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

I have managed to redirect to that specific `#addEmergencyLeave` portion but couldn't put a focus on it.

Any help is very much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean, when saying focus a form? If you'd like to focus first select in your form just use *#employee_list* in your *href*.

Another way is to use an *autofocus* attribute on your select, but I think it's not exactly what you was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can't focus a form, you can only focus a form element, and it is usually achieved using `javascript`.
Add this code into your HTML (before the closing `</body>` element), it will check if the hash `#addEmergencyLeave` is in the URL, and in this case it will focus on the form's first element:

```
<script>
    function onload() {
        if (location.href.indexOf('#addEmergencyLeave') != -1) {
            document.getElementById('employee_list').focus();
        }
    }

    window.addEventListener('load', onload, false);
</script>
```

`addEventListener` is the correct way to add an event listener on `javascript`, here it is the `load` event on the `window` element, usually if you use jQuery you will prefer the document ready event which is way faster.